# Object render has no method call in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have this method in a model -

```
        getDisplayedData: function(){
        data = this.get('data')
        displayedData = this.get('displayedData')
        title = this.get('title')
        newData = [];
        dataToShow = this.get('dataToShow');
        _.each(dataToShow, function(value,key,list){
            nData = data.length;
            for(i = 0; i < nData ; i++){
                row = data[i];
                if(row[title] == value){
                    newData.push(row);
                }
            }
        });
        this.set("displayedData", newData);

        return newData;
    }
```

This is how it's being called-

```
        this.collection.each(function(model,key,list){
        data = model.getDisplayedData();
    });
```

I get this error -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object render has no method 'call'
```

I know this is happening because the this is really a collection object, rather than the DataModel. How do I bind it so that the this refers to the model?

In the init method of my Model I do this-

```
    initialize: function(){
        console.log("INIT MODEL");
        console.log(this);
        return this;
    },
```

This is what prints -

```
    r {cid: "c2", attributes: Object, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object, changed: Object…}
_changing: true
_events: Object
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c2"
collection: r
getDisplayedData: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: s
```

There is no set here - that's the problem(I think).

Comment: Your error is not being raised in getDisplayedData, because there is no reference to 'render' in it. Perhaps you have a bind to the change event in some view? Another thing: your code is very weird, and I am not sure about what it does without a glance in the rest of the code, but displayedData ins your first method is set but never used. Same for data in your loop. Why are you calling this method and seting to the data var, after all? And did you declare these vars before? It looks like to me you have a lot of globals out there.

Comment: Use semicolons. Your code is consistency is awful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
this.collection.models.each(function(model,key,list){
    data = model.getDisplayedData();
});
```